# Calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \frac{4n^2+5n-6}{4n^2+3n-10}\right)^{3-4n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \frac{4n^2+5n-6}{4n^2+3n-10}\right)^{3-4n}$$

Here is my attempt:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \frac{4n^2+5n-6}{4n^2+3n-10}\right)^{3-4n}= \left(\frac{4\infty^2+5\infty-6}{4\infty^2+3\infty-10}\right)^{3-4\infty}$$
$$=\left(\frac{\infty(4\infty+5)}{\infty(4\infty+3)}\right)^{-4\infty}=\left(\frac{4\infty}{4\infty}\right)^{-4\infty} = 1^{-4\infty} = \boxed{1}$$

However, when I try to graph the function, I can't reliably get my answer due to precision limitations, and I feel that this method of calculating limits is less than ideal. How can I confirm that this is indeed the limit?

Comment: Put it in the form $\left[\left(1+\square\right)^{1/\square}\right]^{\frac{\square}{\triangle}}$, where $\square\to0$ and therefore $\left(1+\square\right)^{1/\square}\to e$.

Comment: What is $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$? Is it $\left(1+\frac{1}{\infty}\right)^{\infty}=1^{\infty}=1$?

Comment: Try to divide numerator and denominator by $4n-3$

Comment: I think you can safely omit $-6$ and $-10$ because they are constant terms. Then, you're left with the fraction $\frac{4n+5}{4n+3}$. Then, substitute $m=4n-3$  so $m\to\infty$ and the fraction becomes $\frac{m+8}{m+6}=1+\frac{2}{m+6}$. Omitting the constant $6$, we obtain $\lim_{m\to\infty}(1+2/m)^m$ so the answer should be $e^2$

Comment: @RMWGNE96 You cannot eliminate any of those constants. All of that is incorrect.

Comment: @logarithm in many cases it is allowed, but I'm not sure which conditions must be satisfied so it was a guess, more or less

Comment: @RMWGNE96 You need to check why it is allowed in those cases. For example if you were only computing the limit of $\frac{4n^2+5n-6}{4n^2+3n-10}$, then if you divide by $n^2$ numerator and denominator you get $\frac{4+5/n-6/n^2}{4+3/n-10/n^2}$. Those terms in which the $n$ remained would tend to $0$. Only because the function has this particular form, and due to this argument, those terms end up not being relevant for the final limit. But for other functions any transformation would have to be proven and can easily not remain true.

Comment: Thx for explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\left( \frac{4n^2+5n-6}{4n^2+3n-10}\right)=\frac{(n+2)(4n-3)}{(n+2)(4n-5)}=\frac{4n-3}{4n-5}=\frac{1}{(1-\frac{2}{4n-3})}=(1-\frac{2}{4n-3})^{-1}$$
so
$$\left( \frac{4n^2+5n-6}{4n^2+3n-10}\right)^{3-4n}=(1-\frac{2}{4n-3})^{4n-3}$$
then use

Comment: So the answer should be $\left(e^{-2}\right)^{-1}=e^2$, right?

Comment: @RMWGNE96 the answer should be $\frac{1}{e^2}$

Comment: Oh yes, that also makes sense of course, because you take the negative power of something going to $+\infty$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{4n^2+5n-6}{4n^2+3n-10}\right)^{3-4n}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{4n^2+3n-10+(2n+4)}{4n^2+3n-10} \right)^{3-4n}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{(2n+4)}{4n^2+3n-10} \right)^{3-4n}$$

From $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n+4}{4n^2+3n-10}=0$,

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{(2n+4)}{4n^2+3n-10} \right)^{3-4n}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{(2n+4)}{4n^2+3n-10} \right)^{\left(\frac{4n^2+3n-10}{2n+4}\right)\times \left(\frac{2n+4}{4n^2+3n-10}\right) \times 3-4n}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{(2n+4)(3-4n)}{4n^2+3n-10}}$$

$$=e^{-2}$$

Comment: Could you please explain the transition from $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{(2n+4)}{4n^2+3n-10} \right)^{\left(\frac{4n^2+3n-10}{2n+4}\right)\times \left(\frac{2n+4}{4n^2+3n-10}\right) \times 3-4n}$ to $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{(2n+4)(3-4n)}{4n^2+3n-10}}$?

Comment: @daedsidog  Used definition of exponential function $$e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the other answers, that give you the correct solution,
let me phrase in no uncertain terms that your solution attempt is **very misguided** and will lead you to **wrong results in many cases**.

There are reasons why you almost never see a matematician use thy $\infty$-symbol in a formula like $4\infty+5$. The main reason is that many properties about numbers that we are tought and use intuitively are **not true** if you think about limits reaching an actual 'number' $\infty$.

If you have two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ with the limits $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\infty,\quad \lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=\infty,$$

then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_n-b_n) \text{ could be anything from }+\infty, 2019, 0, -\infty, \text {any other real number or not existing at all.}$$
 You **cannot** model that with the formula $\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_n-b_n)=\infty - \infty$. Once you use $\infty$ as an actual number, you have lost all the information *how* the series converges to $\infty$, which means you cannot tell which of the cases I described is actually correct for two given series $a_n$ and $b_n$.

The same is true for $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$, which you used in your formulas.

The way you handled this shows that you have some correct intuition about limits, but unfortunately at the crucial moment, when you are dealing with

$$\left(\frac{4\infty}{4\infty}\right)^{-4\infty}$$

you are now a victim of what you did before, because you have now no idea *how* either of the terms

$$ \frac{4n^2+5n-6}{4n^2+3n-10} \text{ and } 3-4n$$

converges to $1$ or $-\infty$, resp., which is important to know (if you look at the real solutions).

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I can't believe how few people on Math SE are willing to clearly state the truth. I have also [written about this on MathEd SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10077/1550) but sadly many educators are unwilling to avoid such misguiding pedagogy.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that you want to compute accurately the value of the expression for large values of $n$ and not only the limit.
$$a_n=\left( \frac{4n^2+5n-6}{4n^2+3n-10}\right)^{3-4n}=\left(1+\frac{2}{4 n-5}\right)^{3-4 n}$$ Take logarithms
$$\log(a_n)=(3-4n) \log\left(1+\frac{2}{4 n-5}\right)$$ and use the Taylor expansion
$$\log(1+\epsilon)=\epsilon -\frac{\epsilon ^2}{2}+\frac{\epsilon ^3}{3}-\frac{\epsilon
   ^4}{4}+O\left(\epsilon ^5\right)$$
Make $\epsilon=\frac{2}{4 n-5}$ and continue with Taylor expansion (or long division) to get
$$\log(a_n)=(3-4n)\left(\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\frac{49}{96 n^3}+\frac{17}{32
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\right)$$ that is to say
$$\log(a_n)=-2-\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{13}{24 n^2}-\frac{19}{32
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ COntinue with Taylor using
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=\frac 1{e^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{5}{12 n^2}-\frac{11}{32
   n^3} \right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Try with $n=5$ (which is quite far away from $\infty$. The exact value is
$$a_5=\frac{98526125335693359375}{827240261886336764177}\approx 0.119102$$ while the above truncated expression gives
$$\frac{10567}{12000 e^2}\approx 0.119174$$